# How to use generated accessToken upon Firebase account creation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

After I create user with email and password as below,

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

firebase returns me created user object like this:

```
{
  "uid": "huuX6OwdbfNvthORiDzNV6seo3D3",
  "displayName": null,
  "photoURL": null,
  "email": "qqq2@yahoo.com",
  "emailVerified": false,
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "providerData": [
    {
      "uid": "qqq2@yahoo.com",
      "displayName": null,
      "photoURL": null,
      "email": "qqq2@yahoo.com",
      "phoneNumber": null,
      "providerId": "password"
    }
  ],
  "apiKey": "qqqwwweee",
  "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
  "authDomain": null,
  "stsTokenManager": {
    "apiKey": "qqqwwweee",
    "refreshToken": "AGdpqewb4UYbr5Uo5",
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImI4OWY",
    "expirationTime": 1532487232918
  },
  "redirectEventId": null,
  "lastLoginAt": "1532483591000",
  "createdAt": "1532482346000"
}
```

Then every time I use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method it generates new `accessToken` and `refreshToken`.

But I would like to use `accessToken` until it expires for created user, what method I can use to validate user with this token. So, I do not need to make user sign-in every time.

And method provided for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing internals of a user. These are subject to change. You should rely on the officially documented API. `accessToken` is basically the internal name of Firebase ID token. The correct way to get it is by calling `user.getIdToken()`. This will return the cached token if not expired or will refresh the token under the hood for you.

Comment: So how i will sign user back/authenticate with token? Not with username password?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: After i get user token, how will I use it to recognize/ authenticate the user? What is the method for that? Thanks.

Comment: When you get the ID token, you send it to your server and verify it. Learn more about this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens